# NHibernate, best practice to modify one item from a list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency

I'd like to know what your recommended practice would be when using NHibernate to retrieve a list of items from SQL them modify one, but allowing the maximum concurrency by minimising locking.

I'm following this article: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions
Which says I should use `BeginTransaction` around operations, but I want to manage the concurrency by only locking the update - I don't want to use `BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)` around the gathering of the list.

This scenario is where the condition for selecting which object I want to update can't be done in the select (in my contrived example it's a random pick) but where I want to get, modify and save that object in a locked transaction to ensure that if another thread was modifying the object at the same time, no-one's updates would be lost. I'm assuming the process for choosing which object to modify would not be affected by the object being modified by another thread (perhaps the condition is based on an element of the object not managed by any other threads).

```
using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    ParentEntity[] arr;
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
    {
        arr = session.CreateQuery("from ParentEntity")
            .List<ParentEntity>().ToArray();
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
    // Process results to choose one for modification - for now we'll use a random one
    int i = _rand.Next(arr.Count());
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        ParentEntity par = session.Get<ParentEntity>(arr[i].ID);

        par.data += " modified at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        session.SaveOrUpdate(par);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

So this is getting the full list using `ReadUncommitted`, picking the one to modify, then getting that item again in a `ReadCommitted` transaction and committing it.

Is there a better pattern for managing this sort of operation?

Answer (score 0):

Querying the rows wont lock the table. So you can just read and update the in memory entity.

```
using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    ParentEntity[] arr;
    int i = _rand.Next(arr.Count());
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        arr = session.CreateQuery("from ParentEntity")
            .List<ParentEntity>().ToArray();
        ParentEntity par = arr[i];
        par.data += " modified at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        session.SaveOrUpdate(par);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm experimenting with that model. I expected that the `SaveOrUpdate` would save the object that came from the query so potentially overwrite another update to the same object in another thread. I'm running lots of threads concurrently but not seeing any overwrites (my modified code is re-loading the value) and don't understand why not if, as you say, the query won't lock.

Comment: ...or is the fact that my save/reload finds the same data just caused by level2 caching and the underlying data is getting corrupted by doing a non-locking update? Just found out about 'evict', I'll experiment with that...

Answer (score 0):

I found running this intensely in multiple simultaneous threads, some modifications were lost (one thread would overwrite the results of another).

I've realised my flaw was not configuring 'optimistic locking' which is the technology designed to address the problem I was trying to avoid. Having declared that, principle of the code from Rafael Mueller works fine even when intensely multi threading (also adding retries if `StaleObjectStateException` is thrown).